# passing values from different function to a single object

Tags: java

I have two methods
 1st method has a **object as a return type** and 
2nd method has **integer as a return type**.
I have some values in 1st method and some values in 2nd method
All i want to do is pass all these values to a single object.
**But the problem is only values of 1st method is passing and the values from second method is not passing.**
I am practicing Encapsulation
Below is the code of two files and OUTPUT.

```
//Employee.java file
import java.util.*;
class Employee
{
    private int employeeId;
    private String employeeName;
    private double salary;
    private double netSalary;

    /*public Employee()
    {

    }*/
    public void setEmployeeId(int a)
    {
        employeeId = a;
    }
    public void setEmployeeName(String b)
    {
        employeeName = b;
    }
    public void setSalary(double c)
    {
        salary=c;
    }
    public int getEmployeeId()
    {
        return employeeId;
    }
    public String getEmployeeName()
    {
        return employeeName;
    }
    public double getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }
    public void calculateNetSalary(int pfpercentage)
    {
        netSalary = salary-((salary*pfpercentage)/100);
    }
    public double getNetSalary()
    {
        return netSalary;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.*;
class Main
{
    public static Employee getEmployeeDetails(Employee e)//1st Method
        {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Id:");
                e.setEmployeeId(sc.nextInt());
                sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter Name:");
                e.setEmployeeName(sc.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Enter salary:");
                e.setSalary(sc.nextDouble());
                sc.nextLine();

            }catch(Exception e1){System.out.println("Invalid Input");}
            return e;
        }
        public static int getPFPercentage()//2nd Method
        {
            Employee e = new Employee();
            int pf=0;
            Scanner sc1=new Scanner(System.in);
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Enter PF percentage:");
                pf=sc1.nextInt();
                e.calculateNetSalary(pf);

            }catch(Exception e1){System.out.println("Invalid Input");}
            return pf;
        }
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Employee e = new Employee();
            getEmployeeDetails(e);
            getPFPercentage();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Id : "+e.getEmployeeId());
            System.out.println("Name : "+e.getEmployeeName());
            System.out.println("Salary : "+e.getSalary());
            System.out.println("Net Salary : "+e.getNetSalary());

        }

}
```

```
OUTPUT
Enter Id:
101
Enter Name:
Harry
Enter salary:
20000
-------------1st method is used to take above input
Enter PF percentage:
7
-------------2nd method is used to take only PF percentage input

Id : 101
Name : Harry
Salary : 20000.0
Net Salary : 0.0
```

**Calculation of Net salary is in file Employee.java function name "calculateNetSalary"**

Comment: If you are accessing an attribute inside of a class than use **this** pointer like `this.salary` while setting the value.

Answer (score 0):

You have not calculated `netSalary` before calling method `getNetSalary()`;

```
public void calculateNetSalary(int pfpercentage) //This function should be called first.
{
    netSalary = salary-((salary*pfpercentage)/100);
}
public double getNetSalary()
{
    return netSalary;
}
```

Look below code for better understanding:

```
System.out.println("Salary : "+e.getSalary());
e.calculateNetSalary(5); //Add this line and you will get the required output.
System.out.println("Net Salary : "+e.getNetSalary());
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to take input from user. If u see in the output id, name, salary and pf percentage taken from user

Answer (score 0):

In the 'getPFPercentage' method you are creating a new object but in the main method you are using a different object.

Pass the object that you have created in the main method to the getPFPercentage method

Change you `getPFPercentage` signature to
'public static int getPFPercentage(Employee e)'

Remove the object creation line in the `getPFPercentage` method

and call this method from the main method
- getPFPercentage(e)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside getPFPercentage() method you are creating a new Employee object. You should use the same object created in the main method.

```
public static int getPFPercentage(Employee e)//2nd Method
    {
        int pf=0;
        Scanner sc1=new Scanner(System.in);
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Enter PF percentage:");
            pf=sc1.nextInt();
            e.calculateNetSalary(pf);

        }catch(Exception e1){System.out.println("Invalid Input");}
        return pf;
    }

public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Employee e = new Employee();
        getEmployeeDetails(e);
        getPFPercentage(e);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Id : "+e.getEmployeeId());
        System.out.println("Name : "+e.getEmployeeName());
        System.out.println("Salary : "+e.getSalary());
        System.out.println("Net Salary : "+e.getNetSalary());

    }
```